# Django & Postgres - how can I track down this performance slowdown?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to diagnose a performance issue in a Django application.

The Postgres database is running on a remote server in the cloud, the Django server is running on my local OSX machine.

The database has only about 2 records in it.

This log output shows that the request commences with 2.8 seconds doing something.

DEBUG = False in settings.py

Changing CONN_MAX_AGE seems to make no difference.

How can I track down exactly what it is doing in that time?  I have suspected that it is creating a database connection but I can't seem to find a way to precisely watch connection creation requests between Django and Postgres.

Here is the application output log when executing the view function that starts slow.

The first and second milliseconds output are the same database request repeated.

```
[04/Dec/2018 22:30:14] "GET /main/contact/gsnkn6/view/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7309
start
[]
milliseconds:  2783
[]
milliseconds:  407
milliseconds:  0
milliseconds:  0
```

Here is the code of the Django view function:

```
@require_http_methods(['GET'])
@csrf_exempt
def contact_view(request, contact_slug):
    print('start')
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    contact = Contact.objects.get(slug=contact_slug)
    print(connection.queries)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = end - start
    print(f'milliseconds: ', int(delta.total_seconds() * 1000))
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    try:
        contact = Contact.objects.get(slug=contact_slug)
        print(connection.queries)
    except Contact.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('404 not found')
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = end - start
    print(f'milliseconds: ', int(delta.total_seconds() * 1000))

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    notes_list = Note.objects.filter(
        contact=contact,
    ).order_by(
        '-date_created',
    )
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = end - start
    print(f'milliseconds: ', int(delta.total_seconds() * 1000))

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    related_links_list = RelatedLink.objects.filter(
        contact=contact,
    )
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = end - start
    print(f'milliseconds: ', int(delta.total_seconds() * 1000))

    return render(request, 'main/contact_view.html', {
        'contact': contact,
        'notes_list': notes_list,
        'related_links_list': related_links_list,
    })
```

Here is the database section of my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,
        'USER': 'XXXXX',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXX',
        'HOST': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

pip freeze returns:

```
Django==2.1.3
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1
pytz==2018.7
shortuuid==0.5.0
```

psql -V returns:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.14
```

python version is:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

EDIT:

further information is that setting  DEBUG = True shows that the SQL execution time for the first two queries is about the same 'time': '0.346', even though the first one takes more then 2.5 seconds.

Comment: Did you check the obvious places, such as having an index on `slug` and [the execution plan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216765/postgresql-10-5-slow-query-issue-only-on-macos)?

Comment: @selcuk no I haven't - but given that there is no more than 5 records in the database in total does it make any difference?  Could lack of an index on the slug lead to 2.5 seconds slowdown with less than 5 records?

Comment: OK I created an index and it makes no difference. create index main_contact_slug_index on main_contact (slug);